# Can we write a locally compact metric space as a union of countable compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a locally compact metric space. Can we choose a sequence $H_i$ of compact sets such that $H_i \subset \operatorname{int}\left(H_{i+1}\right)$ for all $i \geq 1$ and $X =\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} H_i$.

Ignore the counterexample : uncountable set with discrete metric. 
Please, provide me some other examples if known.

Comment: Uncountable set with discrete metrics is not necessary. Take any uncountable collection of locally compact metric spaces and then take their disjoint union. The space is metrizable, it is locally compact but doesn't satisfy your condition.

Comment: Compact sets are finite in Discrete metric . So, the countable union of strictly increasing chain of finite sets can be atmost countable.

Comment: What I've meant is that "ignore the uncountable discrete counterexample" is a very weird assumption. It doesn't make anything easier, cause you can replace each point in an uncountable discrete space with a nontrivial locally compact metric space and you still have a counterexample.

Comment: As freakish has pointed out, obvious counterexamples are uncountable disjoint unions of compact spaces (or more generally locally compact spaces). It seems you want counterexamples which do not have such "trivial decompositions".

Comment: Yeah.. I need some non trivial decompositions.

Answer (score 1):

This holds (for metric spaces) iff $X$ is separable as well:

If $X$ is locally compact metric and we have the $H_i$ as promised, $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, hence Lindelöf and separable and second countable (as these are equivalent in all metric spaces).

If $X$ is locally compact metric and separable, we can reduce the base of open sets with compact closure to a countable base $\{B_n: n \in \omega\}$ with all $\overline{B_n}$ compact. Then set $H_0 = B_0$ and cover $\overline{B_0}$ by finitely many new $B_n$, whose union we then define to be $H_1$ etc. continuing by recursion.

Comment: How? Any reference please!

Comment: @AbdulGaffarKhan It's clearly necessary as $X$ is then $\sigma$-compact hence Lindelöf hence separable (and second countable). If second countable (or separable which is the same for metric spaces) we can use a countable base of sets with compact closure to make the $H_i$.

Comment: Let me call the assumption in question be ( * ). By above remarks and the ( * ), we can conclude the following : Assumption (*) holds in a metric $X$ if and only if $X$ is locally compact and separable if and only if $X$ is locally compact and $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: @AbdulGaffarKhan Quite true.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is impossible. A space $X$ which is the countable union of compact subsets is called $\sigma$-compact. It is well-known that if $X$ is locally compact, then $X$ is $\sigma$-compact if and and only it is representable as in your question.

So your question is: Is every locally compact space which is not discrete a $\sigma$-compact space?

Consider an uncountable product $P = \prod_{\alpha \in A} I$ of unit intervals $I = [0,1]$ and $x \in P$. Then $X = P \setminus \{ x \}$ is locally compact. If it were the countable union of compact subsets, then $\{ x \}$ would be the intersection of countably many open neighborhoods. A basis of open neighborhoods is given by the family of sets $\bigcap_{i=1}^n p_{\alpha_i} ^{-1}(U_i)$, where $p_\alpha  : P \to I$ is the projection onto the coordinate $\alpha$, $U_i \subset I$ an open neighborhood of $x_i = p_{\alpha_i}(x)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary. But it is easy to see that any countable intersection of such sets is still an uncountable set since only countably many coordinates are subject to restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for help